# Coding columns for viewing on computer vs mobile

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

A stupidly simple question, but I am new to CSS and very rusty on HTML.

What do I need to add to the following code, to make it so that when view on a mobile, the 2 columns go from a left/right layout to a top/bottom layout?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
  {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Set additional styling options for the columns*/
  .column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  }

  .row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFB695;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
            <p>Data..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#96D1CD;">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
            <p>Data..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer. A media query. Long answer. Use flex instead of float. And use flex-direction column on mobile ( inside a media query )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <style>
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        /* Set additional styling options for the columns*/

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .d-md-flex {
                display: flex!important;
            }
        }
        .flex-grow-1 {
            flex-grow: 1!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="d-md-flex">
    <div class="flex-grow-1" style="background-color:#FFB695;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Data..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1" style="background-color:#96D1CD;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Data..</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why change the classes of the elements ? why add `!important` ? Why no description to your answer ?

Comment: @MihaiT Since everything in the code is understandable, I don't think a description is important. And I changed class for my easiness.

Comment: Never change something for your easiness . You should answer for the OP's understanding.  And yes, even if the code seems to be understandable you should always include a short description about what the code does. And, what about the use of `!important` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the columsn to be responsive. You can do this via flexbox as seen below

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <style>
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Set additional styling options for the columns*/
    .row {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    

    .column {
flex-basis:50%;
}
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFB695;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
            <p>Data..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#96D1CD;">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
            <p>Data..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, if you don't specify any layout-related rules, the blocks will stack on each other (top-bottom), because divs are block level elements.

Then, in your media queries, you can do something like this:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

or, you can go with flex layout from the beginning (ie. in the general, no-media-queries part), and use flex-wrap property.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) instead of `float` for layout purposes.
And change the direction inside a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) ( tweak the breakpoint as you need it )

Using float is ( almost ) never a good ide as it takes the content out of the normal flow of the document. The only usecase where float is acceptable is when you want to wrap some text around an image.

For layout you should use flexbox or css grid.

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
}
.column {
   flex: 0 0 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFB695;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Data..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#96D1CD;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Data..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media Query.

```
  @media(max-width:480px){
           .column {     
             width: 100%;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `display: grid`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(600px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFB695;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Data..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#96D1CD;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Data..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```